Flutter android APP gradle plugin stuck problem
When I run app then stuck
~/Documents/maccode/Dart/flutter_guide_app/android (main) » flutter run                                      icebird@icebirddeMacBook-Pro
Changing current working directory to: /Users/icebird/Documents/maccode/Dart/flutter_guide_app
Launching lib/main.dart on sdk gphone64 arm64 in debug mode...

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Build file '/Users/icebird/Documents/maccode/Dart/flutter_guide_app/android/app/build.gradle' line: 30

* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.
> Could not set unknown property 'minSdkVersion' for extension 'android' of type com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.BaseAppModuleExtension.

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 5s
Running Gradle task 'assembleDebug'...                              6.1s
Error: Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1

here is the flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.2, on macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64, locale zh-Hant-TW)
    • Flutter version 3.22.2 on channel stable at /Users/icebird/Library/Flutter/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision 761747bfc5 (4 周前), 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
    • Engine revision edd8546116
    • Dart version 3.4.3
    • DevTools version 2.34.3

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 35.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/icebird/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-35, build-tools 35.0.0
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.10+0-17.0.10b1087.21-11609105)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.91.0)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.92.0

[✓] Connected device (5 available)
    • sdk gphone64 arm64 (mobile)     • emulator-5554             • android-arm64  • Android 15 (API 35) (emulator)
    • icebird's iphone15+ (mobile)    • 00008120-00023D260CD1A01E • ios            • iOS 17.5.1 21F90
    • macOS (desktop)                 • macos                     • darwin-arm64   • macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64
    • Mac Designed for iPad (desktop) • mac-designed-for-ipad     • darwin         • macOS 14.5 23F79 darwin-arm64
    • Chrome (web)                    • chrome                    • web-javascript • Google Chrome 116.0.5845.179

[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!

build.gradle is under
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = "../build"
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(":app")
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

app/build.gradle is under
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    // The Flutter Gradle Plugin must be applied after the Android and Kotlin Gradle plugins.
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file("local.properties")
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader("UTF-8") { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionCode")
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = "1"
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty("flutter.versionName")
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = "1.0"
}

android {
    namespace = "com.example.flutter_guide_app"
    compileSdk = flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion = flutter.ndkVersion
    minSdkVersion = 21
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId = "com.example.flutter_guide_app"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion = 20
        targetSdkVersion = 30
        versionCode = flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName = flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig = signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source = "../.."
}

the trouble of android
The supplied phased action failed with an exception.
Settings file '/Users/icebird/Documents/maccode/Dart/flutter_guide_app/android/settings.gradle' line: 21
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.3')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository
Plugin [id: 'com.android.application', version: '7.3.3', apply: false] was not found in any of the following sources:
- Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
- Included Builds (None of the included builds contain this plugin)
- Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'com.android.application:com.android.application.gradle.plugin:7.3.3')
  Searched in the following repositories:
    Google
    MavenRepo
    Gradle Central Plugin Repository

the java version used to be 22, and gradle use 7.6.3, looks like Compatibility problem.
So I change Java to java 17
java 17.0.11 2024-04-16 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.11+7-LTS-207, mixed mode, sharing)

also change /Users/icebird/Library/Flutter/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/build.gradle.kts in
// Copyright 2014 The Flutter Authors. All rights reserved.
// Use of this source code is governed by a BSD-style license that can be
// found in the LICENSE file.

plugins {
    `java-gradle-plugin`
    `groovy`
}

group = "dev.flutter.plugin"
version = "1.0.0"

gradlePlugin {
    plugins {
        // The "flutterPlugin" name isn't used anywhere.
        create("flutterPlugin") {
            id = "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
            implementationClass = "FlutterPlugin"
        }
        // The "flutterAppPluginLoaderPlugin" name isn't used anywhere.
        create("flutterAppPluginLoaderPlugin") {
            id = "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader"
            implementationClass = "FlutterAppPluginLoaderPlugin"
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    // When bumping, also update:
    //  * ndkVersion in FlutterExtension in packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy
    //  * AGP version in the buildscript block in packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/groovy/flutter.groovy
    //  * AGP version in the buildscript block in packages/flutter_tools/gradle/src/main/kotlin/dependency_version_checker.gradle.kts
    //  * AGP version constants in packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/android/gradle_utils.dart
    compileOnly("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.0")
}

